# How to add total on cart in PHP

Tags: php

Iam a new Beginner of PHP.
Iam Making a Simple Shopping Cart.
Now I face a problem to add total on cart
My Problem is :- 
When My cart has 2-products ,Its Seen

Total Price: 800Total Price: 860

I want to see Total at 1-Time.
Here is My code :

```
<?php if (!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
  $totalAll = 0;
  foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $key => $value) {

?>

<p style="float: right;" class="h4">Total Price: <?php echo $totalAll = $totalAll + ($value['quantity']*$value['price']);

       ?></p>
<?php
}
} 
?>
```

Comment: count summ in loop `for() {... $totalAll = $totalAll + ...}` and then show it in you echo `$totalAll`

Comment: How can i use for loop there...explain it !plzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal to get Grand Total as:

Example:

```
<?php 
$totalAll = 0; // initialize with 0

// example array with item name, qty, amount, you will use your array here.
$array = array(
            array('qty'=>1,'price'=>8,'name'=>'product 1'),
            array('qty'=>1,'price'=>9,'name'=>'product 2')
            );

// foreach loop for your items.
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   $totalAll += ($value['qty']*$value['price']); // this will save your amount.
}

// print outside the loop which display your grand total at once.
echo "Total PRice: ".$totalAll; // 17
?>
```

In your code, you are using echo inside the loop with `+` increment, which will print twice in your code.

If you want to print at once like Grand Total of shopping cart than you need to save amount inside the loop as mention in example.

**Edit** (example with your code):

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
    $totalAll = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $key => $value) {
        $totalAll += ($value['quantity']*$value['price']);
    ?>
    <?php
    }
}
?>

<p style="float: right;" class="h4">
    Total Price: <?=$totalAll?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, fetch  all data, then write the codes,

```
 $total_quantity= array_sum(array_column($data, "quantity"));
```

It helps to count all quality.
There  $data is an array of all fetch data and another is the column of this array.